# In a stacked (multilayer) LSTM how are the hidden states [h,c] handled?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

Forgive me for my lack of knowledge,

I'm working on a seq2seq problem (a regression problem) using LSTM and I tried finding a comprehensive answer to this question but, I found conflicting answers instead.

I decided to stack lstm layers to increase the prediction accuracy but, later I found out about assigning initial hidden states. I believe I can initialize the hidden states however I want for each layer separately like below:

Layer1_hidden_states = rand()

Layer2_hidden_states = rand()

I know that the output of 1st lstm layer is passed to the 2nd lstm layer as input.

However, If I write return_sequences = True:

Does the 2nd lstm layer take each hidden state [h,c] of previous (1st) lstm layer at each time step and pass it to the 2nd lstm layer in addition to the outputs?

If it does, how is the initial hidden states of 2nd lstm layer combined with the incoming [h,c] from the 1st lstm layer?

Thank you.

Comment: Ok, I just realized that hidden_units of each lstm layer can be different, thefore changing the dimensions of the hidden states for each layer so, it does not make sense to me that hidden_states of the previous lstm layer are passed to the next lstm layer. However, I would appreciate if someone can confirm this for me in case I'm missing something (if the hidden states in fact are passed to the next lstm layer and somehow combined with the hidden states of the next lstm layer). Thank you.

Comment: I think I found the answer: the output is indeed h from [h,c] and is fed as input to the next lstm layer so, return_sequences=true is necessary between lstm layers, except the last lstm layer (depends on whether target is sequence or not).